# countDown или таймер JavaScript

Tags: javascript, таймер, countdown

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так с этим таймером?
Он не останавливается, когда  time = 0
Как мне это исправить?

```
let time = 10;
let timeScreen = document.getElementById('time-left-screen');

function countDown() {
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) < 10 ? '0' + Math.floor(time / 60): Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60 < 10 ? '0' + time % 60: time % 60;
  timeScreen.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  time --;
}

function startGame() {
  if(time >= 0) {
    setInterval(countDown, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(countDown);
  }
}
```

Comment: Вы это сами написали?

Comment: Да. Продолжает считать. И выводит значения с минусами

Comment: В clearInterval надо передавать идентификатор который будет ссылаться на setInterval.
let timerId = setInterval(() => alert('tick'), 2000); setTimeout(() => { clearInterval(timerId); alert('stop'); }, 5000);

Comment: Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы использовать `setInterval` и `clearInterval`, можно почитать **[здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/settimeout-setinterval#setinterval)**. Для вашего примера комментарии в коде:

```js
let timeScreen = document.getElementById('time-left-screen');
let time = 10;
// Объявляем переменную глобально, чтобы 
// она была видна в любых функциях и циклах
let tCount;

function countDown() {
  let minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) < 10 ? '0' + Math.floor(time / 60) : Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60 < 10 ? '0' + time % 60 : time % 60;
  timeScreen.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  // Условие для остановки таймера
  if (time <= 0) {
    // Останавливаем таймер с ID, который находиться в tCount
    clearInterval(tCount);
    console.log(`Таймер с ID = ${tCount} остановлен и удалён.`);
  }
  time--;
}

function startGame() {
  // Запускаем таймер и заносим выданный ID в tCount
  tCount = setInterval(countDown, 1000);
  console.log(`Таймер с ID = ${tCount} создан и запущен.`);
}

startGame();
```

```html
<p id="time-left-screen"></p>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший, полезный ответ для меня